# std list reverse-iterator's past-the-end iterator gets invalidated, if list is empty

Tags: c++, list, iterator

The std::list's reverse past-end iterator gets invalidated, if I modify the list and if the list is empty. But as per the language specification list push_back should have no effect on the iterators:

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>   1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
>   2) value is moved into the new element.
>   No iterators or references are invalidated.

This is as I noticed in the [language spec](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back). Listing example below where I find the behaviour otherwise.

```
//Add or replace an element using reverse iterator
void addOrReplaceRev(std::list<int>& list, int val)
{
    auto rit = std::find(list.rbegin(), list.rend(), val);
    list.push_back(val); //invalidates the rend() iterator, if list empty
    if(rit != list.rend()) //remove if the value existed earlier
        list.erase((++rit).base());

}

void addOrReplace(std::list<int>& list, int val)
{
    auto rit = std::find(list.rbegin(), list.rend(), val);
    bool shouldErase = rit != list.rend(); //save the result before modification
    list.push_back(val);
    if(shouldErase) //All good, as we use saved query result
        list.erase((++rit).base());
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist1;
    std::list<int> mylist2 = {1,2,4,5};

    addOrReplaceRev(mylist1, 3); //empty list messes up with rev iters
    addOrReplaceRev(mylist2, 3); //non-empty lists are fine
    printf("SIZES %d:%d\n", mylist1.size(), mylist2.size());

    std::list<int> mylist3;
    std::list<int> mylist4 = {1,2,4,5};

    addOrReplace(mylist3, 3);//if results are saved
    addOrReplace(mylist4, 3);
    printf("SIZES %d:%d\n", mylist3.size(), mylist4.size());
}
```

The output of the program is

```
SIZES 0:5
SIZES 1:5
```

Note: I don't see this behaviour when I use forward/regular iterators. I'm using gcc 4.9.2 compiler. Is this expected or a compiler bug.

`

Comment: Despite having "iterator" in the name, guarantees that apply to a container's iterators don't necessarily apply to its reverse iterators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse iterators are not the container's iterators, not directly.  They are defined in terms of the container's iterators.

In general, a reverse iterator has a base "normal" iterator.  The element the reverse iterator refers to is not the element the base one refers to, but rather the element *before* the base iterator's element.  (This is because there is no iterator one-before-begin)

`rend` is `reverse(begin)`.  On an empty list, `begin==end`.  So `rend` is `reverse(end)`.

When you insert into the list, no iterators are invalidated.  Your copy of `rend` remains `reverse(end)`, but calling `rend` again returns `reverse(begin)`.  And they are no longer equal.

To me, this seems surprising but I would assume it is compliant.  The C++ standard could not reasonably avoid this "bug".

Comment: `@Yakk` Thanks. I missed the part about `begin` and `end` being equal, for an empty list. Nevertheless, as you said, I'm surprised by this behaviour, especially by the fact that we get two varying behaviours for an empty and non-empty list.